# What is the limit of Scissor rectangles in metal.?

Tags: metal, metal-performance-shaders

I am executing a big file on metal, it is showing the following error:

-[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder initWithRenderCommandEncoder:parent:descriptor:]_block_invoke:807: failed assertion `Exceeded HW limit of scissor rectangles for render encoder working in Memoryless mode.'
Message from debugger: failed to send the k packet

Any way to solve it

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Metal Feature Set tables](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf) (PDF), the limit is 16 for macOS 10.13 (and later, presumably) and 1 everywhere else. Annoyingly, these limits are not query-able programmatically; they're only available in these tables and, as you've found, empirically by exceeding them.